# Teradata: How to split a query to lessen spool size

Tags: sql, select, teradata

I'm having a problem running a very simple query in Teradata that essentially consists of:

```
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, COL5, COL6, COL7, COL8, COL9
FROM table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 on table1.ID = table2.IDN;
```

I expect several million results, but am not precisely certain. The statistics indicate there are about ~8 Million rows.

After getting some resource errors I was informed that as a user I'm limited to 500,000 rows or a 37GB spool size. This query far surpasses both according to the EXPLAIN (as you can imagine). I'm looking for way to do the SELECT in chunks, if possible... unless there is something else that I'm fundamentally missing.

Is this a bad query by nature? Is there a way to split the query into multiple smaller queries?

Comment: It's an unusual query in that there is no `where` clause on a table of ~8M rows. Do you really need every row?

Comment: Perhaps not every row. I could also deal with every row with a date_created within the last 3 years, but I'll still have many more rows than the resource limit allows. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: What are you doing with the data once you get it? If you're aggregating or calculating something, maybe you could do it in SQL instead..

Comment: I'm essentially copying it into another database such that I can index it with Apache Solr. In hindsight I should have set up some kind of streaming index into Solr, but I've been designing and learning as I went and it's too late now :).

Comment: Why don't you simply ask your DBA for more spool space?

Comment: Have your DBAs collected stats on your join columns?  And more importantly, what are you actually trying to do that requires pulling 8 milion rows?

Comment: Is the data you are trying to pull static during the time you execute this query? If yes then you can limit the number the number of rows in a single batch through the Row_Number() operation.